# How do i implement the functionality of a user filtering prices by entering min and max values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I am a newbie in programming and i would like to implement a filtering method where a user filters results based on a price range, i.e they should enter a min price and a max price and get a list of items within that price range.I am using javascript and angular 4 for my front end.

Comment: Can you share what you tried so far?

Comment: Read up on the array method `filter` - your process will be to get the min and max from the user and build a new list from the result of `things.filter((x) => { return x.price > min && x.price < max; })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can just use a filter method to filter out the prices that fall in between min and max with this function:

```
function filterItems(items, min, max){
  return items.filter(item => item.price >= min && item.price <= max);
}
```

Comment: thanks..Seems the `filter` method works fine and all the answers here are working but this one was the easiest for me.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful! Keep moving forward in programming. I would read up on ES6 features. Some are confusing to understand at first but a lot of them are super cool!

Answer (score 1):

You might try the `Array.filter()` method which returns values of an array which match some condition.

Assuming for example, you have an array of price values in a variable called values:

```
var values = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
  min = 15, max = 45;

var filteredValues = values.filter(function(value) {
  // Only keep values which are > min and < max
  return value > min && value < max;
}

// filteredValues will be [20, 30, 40]
```

There are fancier ways of writing this function but hope the plain syntax hopes to make it clear what's going on :)

Or, check out [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).